# Проблема с библитекой undetected_chromedriver [pyhton 3.11.3, win10]

Tags: python

Хотел написать маленький скрипт на питоне для входа на сайт, но не могу понять в чем проблема.

Сам код:

```
import undetected_chromedriver as uc
driver = uc.Chrome()
driver.get('https://nowsecure.nl')
```

Браузер запускается, сразу закрывается и выдает вот такую ошибку:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\usel\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\undetected_chromedriver\__init__.py", line 794, in __del__
  File "C:\Users\usel\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\undetected_chromedriver\__init__.py", line 748, in quit   
OSError: [WinError 6] Неверный дескриптор
```

Comment: Проблема такая же. Причем если использовать driver = uc.Chrome(headless=True,use_subprocess=False), то вылетает другая ошибка.

Answer (score 0):

Такая же проблема, если хочешь чтобы быстро не закрывалось используй time.sleep(60), также не забывай закрыть сам браузер driver.quit()